# Evaluate a limit using Taylor series

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

Let $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{({\ln(1+x) -x +\frac{x^2}{2})^4}}{(\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2})^3}$$

Now, I know that I should utilize Taylor polynomial.

$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - ...$
$\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - ...$

Plugin it into the limit:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{({x-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + R_3(x) -x +\frac{x^2}{2})^4}}{(1-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + S_3(x) -1+\frac{x^2}{2})^3}$$

Simplyfing:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{({\frac{x^3}{3} + R_3(x))^4}}{(\frac{x^4}{4!} + S_3(x))^3}$$

$R_3(x)$ and $T_3(x)$ are the remainders (with order of $3$).
We've learned in class that if you divide the remainder by the same order the limit is still approaces $0$ and I think that's the case here.

I'd be glad if you could show me how to end this exercise and explaining more about the remainder (Which approaches $0$ **even if divided by a polynomial with the same order**).

Thanks!

Comment: You did not use the exponents yet. Starting from your last result, you will get something like
$$\frac{x^{12}/3^4\dots}{x^{12}/(4!)^3\dots}$$

Comment: Take out the $x^3$ in the numerator and the $x^4$ in the denominator.

Comment: I understand. How to explain correctly that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} R_3(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to 0} S_3(x) = 0$?

Comment: You have $R_3(x) = -\frac{1}{4}x^4+ O(x^5)\;$ and similar for $S_3$ and these limits are $0$ for $x\rightarrow 0,\;$ (otherwise the Taylor series would not converge).

Comment: And you're basically using your preliminary knowledge that it is converges. Cool, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You might rearrange and factor some parts of the fraction appropriately to use $$\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\to 1,~~~\frac{\cos x-1}{x}\to 0$$ while $x\to 0$. Note that when $x\to 0$ then, we can simplify something like $\frac{x^4}{x^2}$ and get $x^2$.